# ADO: Execute multiple TSQL using connection and command object

Tags: ado.net

For a particular installation of my application, I need to create the database and the schema on the SQL server from the installer itself. I have a custom installer through which I have been able to detect and install the pre-requisites and the software. The user is prompted to give the IP of the database server and the username and password. Behind the scene, I create a connection and a command object. I keep the queries in different files. I use a reader and read the content of the file and set the content of the file to the `CommandText` of the command object. The typical content of the file is like following:

```
create database mydatabase
Go

Use mydatabase
Go

EXEC sp_MSforeachtable @command1 = "DROP TABLE ?"
```

Now the issue is the first statements get executed but it gives error after that. The error that is shown is: "`syntax error near 'GO'`". I tried removing the GO statement and also tried ending the sql statements with semi-colon. The error in this case is "`Database 'mydatabase'does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.`".

However if I keep a single statement in the file, it works fine.

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258908%28SQL.80%29.aspx

> Remarks
>
> GO is not a Transact-SQL statement; it
>   is a command recognized by the osql
>   and isql utilities and SQL Query
>   Analyzer.

So this is the cause of your problems when you run it using the SqlCommand from .Net. 
In my opinion you have two options:

1) Execute the instructions one by one. Maybe use a separator in your files, then split the SQL statements and execute them sequentially using a for/foreach.

2) Use Server class from SQL Server Management Objects (SMO) that should allow you to execute the script containing "Go" statements.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have already taken up the first option for the time being and looking out for any other viable option for the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can execute more than one sql command statement by simply adding a ";" at the end of each command instead of a "GO" statement.

Example:

```
cmd.CommandText = @" Update TableA Set ColumnA = 'Test' Where ID = 1;
                Update TableB Set ColumnA = 'Second line' Where ID = 2;
          ";
```

Comment: I tried this. But it is not working. If you look carefully towards the end of my post, I am getting the error "Database 'mydatabase'does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly." in this case.